# Relock Y300 Bootloader

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, huawei, bootloader-lock, stock-rom

I have hauwei Y300-0100. I unlocked Bootloader Of My phone before for root it.
Now i want to flash my phone with stock rom but i cant. I tried to lock my phone with fastboot but i gave an error:
[image: error]
I cant solve this problem and i dont have access to phone menu. I have access to TWRP recovery.
How can i lock Y300 boot loader?
or How can i install stock rom on unblock phone?
note:

> system and data folders wiped and there is no data in this folders. My phone is freezing between first logo and welcome picture (A block screen)

Comment: That command is invalid as shown in the picture. I guess you didn't read it anywhere but thought if `unlock`  unlocks the bootloader then `lock` would lock it. Anyhow, why do you want to lock your bootloader just to flash stock ROM? Can't you use a flashable stock ROM zip from Recovery? Or perhaps a fastboot image from fastboot?

Comment: I couldnt find flashable stock rom or image :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved = 
`fastboot oem relock "xxxxxx.."`
xxxx.. = 16 digital code
But if you flashed custom recovery or boot before
you cant relock it